# How to store objects dynamically created from a hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm new to ruby, and apologies in advance as I strongly suspect I'm missing something really obvious here. But..

I'm trying to create objects dynamically, based on an array of hashes.  But how do I store the objects?

If I was creating just one, I'd do a variable assignment like so:

```
h = PuppetNode.new(hash)
print h.hostname # foo.bar.com
```

but what about here?:

```
array_of_hashes.each { | hash |
  h = PuppetNode.new(hash) 
}
```

This will result in the 'h' object being overwritten won't it? 
I suppose I could try to extract something from the hash to name the variable dynamically, but it seems like it is unnecessary as various instance variables mark out the unique-ness of each object.

Do I really need to use a variable at all? If not, how do I create/store the objects. If so, how can I dynamically set the variable name without painful regex use?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you want the output to be exactly, I'm unclear.

Comment: (error corrected in my code example)      Imagine 'array_of_hashes' is three hashes. How do I get three objects, which I can refer to in the same way as I did in my first example, with h.hostname

Comment: `nodes = array_of_hashes.map { | hash | PuppetNode.new(hash) }` will yield an array of `PuppetNode` objects.  You can then access them as `p nodes[0].hostname`

Comment: You always want a container to hold multiple objects. An array is usually good to serve as a container, but there are other choices such as a set, a stack or a queue based on your use case.

Comment: Of course, use an array. That map function is perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store multiple objects, you can use a collection object to do that. Ruby comes with two kinds of collection objects built into the core library: [`Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html) (a linear sequence of elements addressable by numeric index) and [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html) (a mapping from key objects to value objects, addressable by key). In the standard library, there are additional kinds of collection objects such as [`Set` (a collection that tracks membership of values) and `SortedSet`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/).